# Is there an issue having Windows-only gems in Gemfile.lock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems, bundler

When run bundle install on Windows, the Gemfile.lock gains a few gems that are Windows only, for example:

```
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1-x86-mingw32)
```

Is there any problem having those on the Gemfile.lock and deploying them to production (Linux)?

Comment: Developing on a virtual machine that is close to your production environment is a good practice, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having many of those windows-only statements in the Gemfile.lock and deploying to both Heroku and our own servers I can confirm that no, it's not a problem, at least not with recent copy of bundler (1.1.4 at the time of this writing).

Answer (score 2):

If the bundler is newer then version `1.1.2` it will remove `bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1-x86-mingw32)`  automaticaly.

Here is discussion around that issue:

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/635

Comment: What do you mean by remove? we are running bundle 1.1.3 on both machines, the Windows machine added the mingw32 version, the osx machine didn't remove it. Not even running bundle update removed the ming32 version.